# Using QT resource with PYQT6 to play sound

Tags: python, pyqt6

I wrote a specific code to use sound in a Python program. It works but I can't use it with a resource file.

I wrote code to play a sound. It works.

```py
from PyQt6.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt6.QtMultimedia import QMediaPlayer,QAudioOutput
import ressources_rc

def play(self, son ="sounds/clic.mp3"):
    self.player = QMediaPlayer()
    self.audio = QAudioOutput()
    self.player.setAudioOutput(self.audio)
    self.player.setSource(QUrl.fromLocalFile(son))
    self.player.play()
```

But I want to use the resource system. I compiled the sound in the specific file.

```py
from PyQt6.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt6.QtMultimedia import QMediaPlayer,QAudioOutput
import ressources_rc

def play(self, son =":/sounds/sounds/clic.mp3"):
    self.player = QMediaPlayer()
    self.audio = QAudioOutput()
    self.player.setAudioOutput(self.audio)
    self.player.setSource(QUrl.fromLocalFile(son))
    self.player.play()
```

When I enter the resource link in place of a local link, I obtain an error: `handleSourceError: 0x8007007B`

What's wrong? How can I fix this?

Comment: Qt resources are not "local files", just use `QUrl(son)`.

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution : add **"qrc"** in the url link

the new code is :

```
from PyQt6.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt6.QtMultimedia import QMediaPlayer,QAudioOutput
import ressources_rc
    
def play(self, son ="qrc:/sounds/sounds/clic.mp3"):
    self.player = QMediaPlayer()
    self.audio = QAudioOutput()
    self.player.setAudioOutput(self.audio)
    self.player.setSource(QUrl(son))
    self.player.play()
```